# parsing user input into predefined json format

Tags: android, json, autocomplete, nlp, word-processor

I'm building a workout app and I've been wrestling with how to enable users to define their exercises. I want to avoid multiple text fields of input and i was hoping to allow users to enter the whole thing via text and then parse their entry into my predefined model for a workout.

There aren't infinite ways to define exercises in a workout ("3 sets of 10, 9 and 8 reps at 100, 120 and 130 (lbs | kg)", "set 1. 30 seconds with 40 seconds rest, set 2. ...."). So at first i thought about doing simple string parsing but im wondering if there are existing libraries/algorithms/methodologies I could use to help

This is an android app and I'm hoping to do the computation locally

I was also hoping to include implementing auto complete like in google search.

My model is as such, a workout is just a collection of these

```
var exerciseTemplate = {
"exerciseTemplateId" : UUID,
"exerciseMetadataId" : UUID,
"defaultTargetQuantity": {
    "sets" :{
        {
            "setId":UUID,
            "setOrder": Integer,
            "weight" : Float,
            "unit" : (lbs | kg),
            "reps" : Integer | "time" : Integer | "untilFailure" : Boolean,
            "rest" : Integer
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have just learned [IMS Question & Test Interoperability(QTI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QTI) which defines a standard format for the representation of assessment content and results, supporting the exchange of this material between authoring and delivery systems, repositories and other learning management systems.

You can see [here](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/index.html)  if it can help you,but it is XML format.